# firefox extension how to access the sidebar elements

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

If I have a sidebar in my firefox extension. How do I access certain elements like textboxes with my sidebar javascript to modify their value?

Comment: Do you want to access html "input" elements in the loaded page or XUL [textboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox)?

Comment: I want to update XUL textboxes in my sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access the sidebar from script overlaying browser.xul (or indeed access the the browser from sidebar script) check out these [code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Sidebar).

Answer (score 1):

By following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Sidebar

I got the following to work for an add-on I wrote:

```
function displayOnSideBar(text) {
    const win = document.getElementById("sidebar").contentWindow;
    dump("location.href:" + win.location.href);
    if (win.location.href == "chrome://scrapbook/content/scrapbook.xul") {
        const label = win.document.getElementById("toolbar-label");
        label.value = text;
        return true;
    } else {
        dump("displayOnSidebar return false");
        return false;
    }
},
```

In scrapbook.xul I have something like:

```
<toolbar id="sbMainToolbar">
    .....
      <!-- this is useful for other add-ons such as simple-timer
       to display some information -->
  <label id="toolbar-label" value="" flex="1"/>
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Set the id on the textbox. Use this to access it:

```
document.getElementById("theId").value = "new text";
```